# I want to make my Office 365 connected team site the root site for my org so I can provide an org calendar that everyone uses

Tags: calendar, team-sites, calendar-view

Our IT support hasnt been much help, but anytime we want to create things like share mailboxes or shared calendars (like an org-wide calendar to show things like events and PTO) they would just create new user accounts in Office 365 and then change permissions on the mailboxes and calendars so people can access them.

But we recently transitioned to Office 365 and because of that we get SharePoint.  I know enough about SP to know that when creating a Team site, that site gets some Office 365 features like a calendar which is great. I could create a team site add everyone as a member to it and BOOM, the group calendar is automatically added to their Outlook.  BUT apparently we cannot do that, the current root site is a "communications" site and I cannot replace it with my newly created team site because "This site must be a team site or communication site. It can't be connected to a Microsoft 365 Group."

So If I cannot use this team site as the root, does that mean that we *have* to use some random user account for the calendar?

Also - How does one even display a calendar view on Sharepoint? There doesnt seem to be any sort of support for that which is weird because it seems like such a basic feature.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make the root site a Teams-connected site. If your Microsoft 365 tenant is fresh, then it might not even be that painful. Here are the list of steps:

1. Create a fresh Team site
2. Swap the new site with the root site using the `Invoke-SPOSiteSwap` command. [Read about it here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/invoke-spositeswap?view=sharepoint-ps)
3. Move the content of your old team-enabled site to the root site
4. Team-connect the root site. You will see a button in the bottom-left corner to do it.

**Adding a group calendar to your page**

Currently, there is only one modern webpart called "[Group Calendar](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-group-calendar-web-part-eaf3c04d-5699-48cb-8b5e-3caa887d51ce)". It only shows a few events at a time and does not look like a calendar, but it's better than nothing:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't use site swap on a Teams connected site, or any group connected site.  This can only be done with non-group connected sites.

Comment: Exactly, @JoshMcClanahan. Ths is exactly why I mention that we need to create a new site collection.